# Making a NULL field in a MySQL row appear as a value?

Tags: php, mysql

The only way I can think of doing this is with a bunch of If statements by carrying over the values. Does MySQL currently have a query function that can display a certain value (Lets say, MTNDEW) as another if it falls under the correct qualifications (If ["soda"] = MTNDEW then display it as Mountain_Dew)? Sorry if I'm not being clear, my English is not very good.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results.  Also, what does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: Sorry, that was the original question, I just got sidetracked and forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want the mysql if function 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

```
SELECT IF(soda='MTNDEW','Mountain_Dew',' NOT Mountain_Dew');
```